# How to prove second order differentiation matrix is of the form..

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Given that the matrix:

> $$D2 = \left[\begin{matrix}a11&a12&a13\\a21&a22&a23\\a31&a32&a33\end{matrix}\right]$$

is a second-order differentiation matrix in the sense, for a function u defined and twice differentiable on the interval [a,b],

> $$\left[\begin{bmatrix}u"(a)\\u"(\frac{a+b}{2})\\u"(b)\end{bmatrix}\\  ≈D2\begin{bmatrix}u(a)\\u(\frac{a+b}{2})\\u(b)\end{bmatrix}\right]$$

with the approximation being exact for polynomials of degree as high as possible.

> Prove that,
>    $$D2=k\left[\begin{matrix}1&-1&1\\1&-1&1\\1&-1&1\end{matrix}\right]$$

If someone could just let me know how to start this, that would be great.